# Dropdown and Linkbutton event not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a problem. I have a control page.  when I click on linkbutton "lnk1_click" the event  "ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" is run.  I need autopostback to my dropdown, because I change the value of my dropdown after the click on the dropdown.
Why the event firing is not good?  How resolve the problem?

thanks for your help

```
<div>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" OnClick="lnk1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk2" runat="server" OnClick="lnk2_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
<div >
<div class="">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you click the lnk1 button, you want a selection to be made in the dropdown list?

Comment: Not, I would like when I click on the lnk1 button, the event "lnk1_Click" is run and not "ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"